# Closure of sequence having finite non zero terms

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\Bbb{R}^{\omega}$ in product topology and uniform topology where the uniform topology is generated by the uniform metric $$\overline{\rho}((x_n), (y_n))= \sup \{ |x_n-y_n|\}.$$ Let $S$ be the set of sequences in $\Bbb{R}^{\omega}$ having finite number of non zero terms.

$\omega$ is a countably infinite set and $\Bbb{R}$ is the set of real numbers with the Euclidean topology.

What is the closure of $S$ in both these topologies?

I think the closure of $S$ is $S$ itself in both the topologies. I mean if I take a point outside $S$, I can find an open set containing that point which doesn't intersect with $S.$ Am I right ?

Comment: No, the box topology and this topology does not always coincide.

Answer (score 1):

For the uniform topology:

It's easy to see that 
$S\subset T:=\{\overline{x}\in \Bbb{R}^{\omega}\ |\ \overline{x}=(x_n)_\omega\ \mathrm{and\ } \forall \varepsilon>0\exists N\in \Bbb{Z}_+ \forall n\geq N :|x_n|<\varepsilon\}$, (i.e., the set of all real sequences that converge to $0$.)

If $y\notin T$ , then there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that for every $k∈\Bbb{Z}_+$ there is $n_k≥k$ such that $|y_{n_k}|\geq\varepsilon.$ Hence, if $z\in$ $B_\overline{\rho}(\overline{y},\frac{\varepsilon}{2})$ , for every $k\in\Bbb{Z}_+$, $|z_{n_k}|>|y_{n_k}|−\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\geq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, and $B_\overline{\rho}(\overline{y},\frac{\varepsilon}{2})$ does not contain any points of $T$.

Therefore, $T$ is closed and contains the closure of $S.$ At the same time, for every $x\in T$ and $\varepsilon >0$ , there is $N\in\Bbb{Z}_+$ such that for $n≥N,$ we have: $|x_n|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, and $$\overline{y}=(x_1,…,x_N,0,0,…)\in B_\overline{\rho}(\overline{y},\frac{\varepsilon}{2})\cap S.$$

So, the closure of $S$ in the uniform topology is the set of all sequences of real numbers converging to zero in $\Bbb{R}$.

For the product topology, one can show that $cl{S}$ is the whole space as follows:

If $\Bbb{R}^{\omega}$ is given the product topology, let $\overline{x}= (x_n)_\omega$ be any member of $\Bbb{R}^\omega$ and $U=\prod_{\omega} U_n$ be any neighbourhood of $\overline{x}$, where for all but finitely many values of $n$ , $U_n=\Bbb{R}$. We construct a point $\overline{y}\in S$ by choosing a point $y_n \in U_n$ if $U_n \subsetneq \Bbb{R}$ and  $y_n=0$  if $U_n=\Bbb{R}.$

Since $U_n$ is a proper subset of $\Bbb{R}$ for only finitely many values of $n$, $y\in S$ and hence, $y\in U\cap S.$ 
It is then clear that $\overline{x}\in cl{S}$, thus $cl{S}=\Bbb{R}^\omega.$

In fact, one can show that $S$ is closed in the box topology, so this is also a good example to show that all these topologies can be in fact distinct.